# How would I get a function to return True or False if the argument that is inputted is a symbol? (ex. %$#@)

Tags: python

As a beginner practice I have to create a function that returns `True` if ALL the letters in the string are uppercase. I am able to do that but it is returning `False` if only a string of symbols is inputted (ex. `#$%`) when it should be returning `True`.

Here is the code, it will return `True` if all letters are capital & include symbols but will not return `True` if only containing symbols.

```
def is_uppercase(inp):
    if inp.isupper() and inp != int:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The exact input that is failing is `$%&`.

Comment: What is `inp != int` supposed to do?

Comment: At any rate, code of the form `if condition: return True else: return False` can and should always be replaced by `return condition`.

Comment: Numbers, symbols and spaces are not checked when using isupper()

Comment: [inp != int] was used to make sure that inp was not an integer. While looking at it it does not appear to do much but when added to my code it passed more tests than without it.

Comment: Assuming `inp` is a string, `inp != int` will _always_ be true.

Comment: That isn’t what `inp != int` does. `inp == int` would *only* be true if `inp` was a *function* — namely, the function `int` (which creates an integer from its argument, e.g. `int("1")`.

Comment: So you want the function to return true if the input is all uppercase letters, or all symbols?  What if the input is a mixture of those?

Comment: Oh okay, thank you very much! What would you use to weed out the symbols? Would I have to manually input them in a way such as `if inp is in ["%","$","&"] return True` ?

Comment: Responding to John: If it is a mixture of the two, it appears to already return True. Which is why I am wondering why it is returning False if only containing symbols but True when only containing uppercase letters or both letters and symbols

Comment: @KonradRudolph `return condition` is bad if you want a `bool` and `condition` isn't one.

Comment: Use regular expression

Comment: @KellyBundy Potentially, and in this situation you should use `bool(condition)` to cast the result, rather than using a convoluted conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, `.isupper()` will return `False` for anything that is not an uppercase character, including symbols and digits. You will need to use the inverse (`not`) of `.islower()` instead. You should also iterate over the string and check each character individually:

```
def is_uppercase(inp):
    return not any(i.islower() for i in inp)
```

The `(i.islower() for i in inp)` part is a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/) that iterates over the string and returns the `.islower()` value of the next character every time it's called.

`any()` will compute every value of the generator expression until it finds `True`.

`not` will inverse the output.

Basically it will return `False` if it finds a non-uppercase character, and `True` if it can't.

Answer (score 1):

you would probably need to use the `string.punctuation` from the `string` library

```
import string

def isSymbol(word:str) -> bool:
    return all(c in string.punctuation or c.isupper() for c in word)

print(isSymbol('!@#$%^&*()_+'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check whether uppering it changes it:

```
def is_uppercase(inp):
    return inp == inp.upper()
```

Or you could add an uppercase letter to satisfy `isupper`'s "[and there is at least one cased character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper)" criterion:

```
def is_uppercase(inp):
    return (inp + 'A').isupper()
```

Benchmark results (due to Selcuk's comment):

```
'$%&'
0.00206354699912481 Kelly1
0.0024452939978800714 Kelly2
0.007135316991480067 Selcuk

0.002112452988512814 Kelly1
0.002419316995656118 Kelly2
0.006345021014567465 Selcuk

0.0020082010014448315 Kelly1
0.002397250005742535 Kelly2
0.006479812000179663 Selcuk


'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
0.005014711001422256 Kelly1
0.005423808004707098 Kelly2
0.005639064009301364 Selcuk

0.00503394499537535 Kelly1
0.005443221016321331 Kelly2
0.005748191004386172 Selcuk

0.005227680987445638 Kelly1
0.0053241550049278885 Kelly2
0.00574598801904358 Selcuk
```

So even if mine have to process 300 characters while Selcuk's only checks the first character, mine are still a bit faster.

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBLTsQwDN33FF4wJClR1aEs0EhdsGbJAaoM40BEfvKkQj19SZoKgcYbK8/vYycu6TP44TnSumoKDpJxaBIYFwMlIIyoUtNcUMMrWrscufFRnBrIRZhm8pABGMfSujlGJC7@8B9v@QWBB2AvTHTm@k/yhvZ9/rqV@JBA@YWbLLDhuwhABwKTU0twlm/PbJwBdne4ZxKYYu3Q98UokvGJ52No8xYZKvypsEn5D@TDHlhgXeB6rdyvkPtqlQSQYARnPK//w61y54s6gd7sJfjZnZHGY9@2T1taqbpEkqC7afLK4TTVUR2I3z3Fuv4A)):

```
from timeit import repeat

def Kelly1(inp):
    return inp == inp.upper()

def Kelly2(inp):
    return (inp + 'A').isupper()

def Selcuk(inp):
    return not any(i.islower() for i in inp)

for inp in '$%&', 'a'*300:
  print(repr(inp))
  for _ in range(3):
    for f in Kelly1, Kelly2, Selcuk:
      t = min(repeat(lambda: f(inp), number=10**4))
      print(t, f.__name__)
    print()
  print()
```

Comment: Computationally more intensive, but easy to understand.

Comment: @Selcuk See the added benchmark :-)

Comment: True, they have different average/worst case/best case outcomes.

Comment: @Selcuk Yeah, I already gave yours a best case there. I now also tried `'A'*300`, a worst case for yours. Results: Kelly1=0.005, Kelly2=0.022, Selcuk=0.249. So almost 50 times faster there.

Comment: Why would 300 be the "best" or "worst" case? Where does 300 come from? Try `"a"*500`, or `"a"*5000`. We don't really know the use case for the OP.

Comment: @Selcuk It's not about the 300. It's about the `'a'` vs `'A'`. With `'a'` it's a best case for you, since you only check a single character. With `'A'` it's a worst case for you, since you check *every* character. The 300 is just roughly the break-even point, where your solution finally becomes faster (on best case content).

Comment: My point is your benchmark only tests inputs where your method performs better. An input is not separable from its size (that's the N in O(N) notation). In the average case (random distribution of printable characters, as in `"".join(random.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(500))`) my method starts to perform better after roughly N>500. Obviously we don't know what a typical input for the OP is, therefore this discussion is moot. Also the complexity has nothing to do with "checking every character" as your methods (have to) check every character as well.

Comment: @Selcuk I didn't use those inputs because my solution is faster on them, I used them because one is the OP's only example and the other is one where we're about *equally* fast. What do you mean with *"An input is not separable from its size"*? Does that refer to me calling cases starting with `'a'` best cases, without talking about size? That's standard. Like you'd also say already sorted arrays are best cases for insertion sort. Equally without talking about size. I doubt they have random strings, so didn't even try speculating about "average". Your last sentence is odd, first half is ...

Comment: ... wrong and second half is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isalpha()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha))

```
def is_uppercase(inp):
    return inp.isupper() and inp.isalpha()
```

---

By the way, if you want to make a check to ensure `inp` is not a `int`, the `inp != int` will not work as you expected.

```
>>> 1 != int
True
```

The correct way to check it is:

```
>>> not isinstance(1, int)
False
```

The solution with type guard:

```
def is_uppercase(inp):
    if isinstance(inp, int):
        return False
    return inp.isupper() and inp.isalpha()
```